# junit mockito use same object for controller and service method

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public User login(@RequestBody User user){
            User u = userService.validateUser(user);
            if(u != null){
                return u;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

This is my test case for my controller

```
@Test
    public void testUserController() throws Exception {
         User u = new User();
         u.setEmail("12a@gm.com");
         u.setPassword("00000");
         Gson gson = new Gson();
         String data = gson.toJson(u);
         when(userService.validateUser(u)).thenReturn(new User());
         String response = mockMvc.perform(post("/login").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(data)).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
         assertTrue(response.equals("hi"));
    }
```

I'm converting the User object to string and posting it to the controller method. I'm trying to mock the service method where userService.validateUser() will return new empty User object. Since the object posted to service method and the object received by controller is different, service is returning null. How can i make service method return empty user Object?

Answer (score 0):

The user object you create in test case (which is passed `mockMvc`) is a different instance of the object that is passed in `login` method.

You could use the wildcard acceptance in your `when().then()`:

```
when(userService.validateUser(Mockito.any(User.class))).thenReturn(new User());
```

or the syntax I would use:

```
doReturn(new User()).when(userService).validateUser(Mockito.any(User.class));
```